# Set imageview foreground gradient color programmatically

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, gradient

I have xml gradient drawable resource file here:

file: fg_graidient

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <gradient
        android:type="linear"
        android:centerX="0%"
        android:startColor="#00020321"
        android:centerColor="#F2000000"
        android:endColor="#B2020321"
        android:angle="45"/>
</shape>
```

I can the imageview foreground like below:

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backimg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:foreground="@drawable/fg_graidient"
            />
```

But I want to set this drawable foreground for imageview programmatically. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Create programmatically gradient shapes

```
ShapeDrawable.ShaderFactory sf = new ShapeDrawable.ShaderFactory() {
    @Override
    public Shader resize(int width, int height) {
        LinearGradient lg = new LinearGradient(0, 0, width, height,
            new int[]{Color.GREEN, Color.GREEN, Color.WHITE, Color.WHITE},
            new float[]{0,0.5f,.55f,1}, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);
        return lg;
    }
};

PaintDrawable p=new PaintDrawable();
p.setShape(new RectShape());
p.setShaderFactory(sf);
```

use

```
Button btn= (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
btn.setBackgroundDrawable((Drawable)p);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this snipet:

```
 ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.backimg);
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.fg_graidient);
```

Comment: img.setImageResource will replace my imageview instead of adding gradient to the image background or foreground, so it is absolutely wrong